# Parse image from json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to get all my images (for futher converting to canvas) from plain json string...

For example i can have in json string:

```
<p>someText</p>
<img src="">
```

or

```
asdasdasasd
asdasdasd
asd <img class="asd" src="123">
```

and i use it so:

```
var html = $.parseHTML(someString)
```

**

```
.children('img')
.find('img')
```

but those functions didn't work(

How can i get all my img objects from this html? So, that i can further use it with `drawImage` (canvas)

is it possible?

**upd**

via ajax i get, for example, such data:

```
<p>someText</p>
<img src="">
```

or

```
asdasdasasd
asdasdasd
asd <img class="asd" src="123">
```

or

```
<h3><p>someText <img src=""></p><h3>
```

etc...

and somehow i need to convert this string to a 'virtual' DOM, where i can get images (and other elements too) and manipulate with them with jQuery. Like i can fetch images for my window-object: `$('img')` - this will fetch all images from page body. And i need something similar for my string. So, that i can use this images with jQuery.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking. What is this *"json string"*? Does it contain the html shown? And where are you using `.children().find()`?

Comment: A workaround, wrap your HTML (you get from your *"json string"*) in a Root-Element: `$('<div><p>someText</p><img src=""></div>').find('img')` or `$('<div></div>').append($('<p>someText</p><img src="">')).find('img')` Not sure what a better/easier solution would be.

Comment: If it is only the html shown, change `find()` to `filter()` since the image is at root level of that html

Comment: @charlietfl yes, string contain such elements as described. I tried `html.children('img')`, `$(html).children('img')` (and same with find)

Comment: We need more code context. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array after the parseHTML function. I think, you should traverse it and look that if it is an image, get it and add $(array_element).

After this process, you will get a Jquery object that can use attr(), find() etc. functions.

```js
var k    = '<p>sosmeT22ext2</p><img class="c" src="empty"><img class="empty" src="123">';
var html = $.parseHTML(k);

for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
    if(html[i] instanceof HTMLImageElement){
        console.log($(html[i]).attr("src")); // all jquery functions works on $(html[i])
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Update

Above code doesn't work in nested dom html. Because it just traverse in one level as you see. Below code is more complicated beacuse it is a recursive method. My suggestion is that, if your dom is not nested use the first code block, it is not use the recursive method to extract and use your images.

```js
var k    = '<div><p>s133o4s3meT232ext2</p><img class="c" src="empty"><img class="empty" src="123"></div>';
var html = $.parseHTML(k);

var images_arr = [];
get_child_nodes(html);
console.log(images_arr[1].attr("src"));

function get_child_nodes(html_l){
    for(var i = 0; i < html_l.length; i++){
        if(html_l[i] instanceof HTMLImageElement){
            images_arr.push($(html_l[i]));
        }
        else {
            for(var j = 0; j < html_l[i].childNodes.length; j++){
                get_child_nodes($(html_l[i].childNodes[j]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @charlietfl thank you charlie, I didn't think for the examples but you are right I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment, found the actual solution for your Problem:

```
> $('<p>someText</p><img src="">').filter('img')
[img]
```

The problem is that your HTML does not have a child which can be an img, but one of the root elements is, filter takes the root elements into account.

Compare (bad/worse but finds nested):

```
> $('<div><p>someText</p><img src=""></div>').find('img') 
> $('<div></div>').append($('<p>someText</p><img src="">')).find('img')
```

Solution that always works, combining the selectors `find` and `filter` without creating an extra root element:

```
> $('<p>someText</p><img src=""><div><img></div>').filter('img')
[img]
> $('<p>someText</p><img src=""><div><img></div>').find('img')
[img]
> h = $('<p>someText</p><img src=""><div><img></div>')
[p, img, div]
> h.find('img').add(h.filter('img'))
[img, img]
```

Comment: Your comment above about the wrapper might also be proper approach depending on if images might be nested also or not. Then `find()` would get all images regarding of nesting level

Comment: Yes, but not for the examples Op has shown, assuming that's all he needs.

Comment: Right, I'm only suggesting that if example is over simplified and there could be unknown structure

Comment: @charlietfl check upd

Comment: Over-complicated it . `var $images = $('<div>').html(HtmlString).find('img')`

Comment: That's the reason why I usually only review edits anymore.